# What is the difference between () and (()) in the control structures?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a doubt regarding the control structures. Well, I always opened and closed the parentheses, this only once => `()`

What happens is that I recently came to realize that some people use two parentheses `(())` of opening and closing, but what is the real meaning of that, what is the difference?

What is the difference between the scripts below?

*First*

```
<?php


$string = "Hello World!";


if ( $string == "Hello World!" ) {
    print(1); //True
} else {
    print(0); //False
}
```

*Second*

```
<?php


$string = "Hello World!";


if (( $string == "Hello World!" )) {
    print(1); //True
} else {
    print(0); //False
}
```

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: It's called pointless decoration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference.

The first set of parentheses is required by the syntax of `if`. It's always

```
if (expression)
```

Inside the expression you may need to use parentheses to group subexpressions, either to override default operator precedence or to make the precedence clear to readers.

But an extra set of parentheses around the entire expression has no effect. It's redundant, just as in something like:

```
$x = $a + $b;
```

and

```
$x = ($a + $b);
```

Comment: I'm still waiting for you to upload a high-res photo :)